# Problem with Blender Asset-Library reading catalogues

Tags: path, asset, library

So I have some asset packs I got and downloaded to my desktop where I marked them as assets, and created catalogues in asset library for them. There is now a txt file in the folder with the blends that shows all the names and hierarchies of the catalogue. I then moved that folder to the storage folder where I place all my assets and which is assigned for Blender as asset library storage, and now when I open any of the blends that were on the desktop, or open a new file and go to Assets, they are all unassigned and my catalogues are lost. I tried refreshing the path from the preferences settings but that didn't help. How to get Blender to read the txt file and connect them all in proper hierarchy again?